# How do I include on certain values when summing from a powershell array?

Tags: powershell, sum

I want to get a sum for the total space a SQL server is using for Data and Log files.
From a few other sources on the internet I have the following code: (Yes, I'm a Powershell Noob)

```
$servers = "SQLSERVER1"
$array = @()
foreach($server in $servers){
    $sysinfo =  Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $server
    for($i = 0;$i -lt $sysinfo.Count; $i++){
        $sname =  $sysinfo[$i].SystemName
        $servername = $server
        $label = $sysinfo[$i].Label
        if(($label) -and (!($label.Contains("FILLER")))){
            write-host "Processing $label from $server"
            $name = $sysinfo[$i].Name
            $capacity = [math]::round(($sysinfo[$i].Capacity/1GB),2)
            $fspace = [math]::round(($sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace/1GB),2)
            $sused = [math]::round((($sysinfo[$i].Capacity - $sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace)/1GB),2)
            $fspacepercent =  [math]::Round((($sysinfo[$i].FreeSpace*100)/$sysinfo[$i].Capacity),2)
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerName" -Value $server
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Label" -Value $label
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $name
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Used(GB)" -Value $sused
            $array += $obj
        }
    }
    $array += write-output " "
    $totalSize = ($array | Measure-Object 'Used(GB)' -Sum).Sum
    $array += $totalsize
    $array += write-output " "
}
$totalsize
```

This gives me the result of:

```
Processing Recovery from SQL-Group1-DB
Processing System from SQL-Group1-DB
Processing SQLInstall from SQL-Group1-DB
Processing OCTOPUS from SQL-Group1-DB
Processing SQL_DATA from SQL-Group1-DB
Processing SQL_LOG from SQL-Group1-DB
Processing TEMP_DB from SQL-Group1-DB
Processing SSS_X64FREV_EN-US_DV9 from SQL-Group1-DB
274.92
```

Of course that has included EVERY drive on the server.
I only want the SQL_DATA and SQL_LOG drives included.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?
(Happy to use entirely different code if it works)
TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the info for all drives on the server, you could limit the results of the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet in the `$sysinfo` variable by using a `Where-Object{}` clause like:

```
$sysinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -ComputerName $server | 
           Where-Object { 'SQL_DATA', 'SQL_LOG' -contains $_.Label }
```